# Using integers from columns as slice indexers of a string in another column

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6, slice

I have a df:

```
string_pos = {'string': [ 'aabb', 'ddcc', ],
              'position_1': [0, 1],
              'position_2': [3, 4]}
```

output:

```
    string  position_1  position_2
0    aabb        0          3
1    ddcc        1          4
```

Then I write what I think will add a new column with a substring of the 'string' column:

```
df['short_string'] = df.string.str[df['position_1'], df['position_2']]
```

But it returns:

```
    string  position_1  position_2  short_string
  0  aabb       0           3           NaN
  1  ddcc       1           4           NaN
```

I am trying to get:

```
    string  position_1  position_2  short_string
  0  aabb       0           3           aab
  1  ddcc       1           4        dcc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need process by each row by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `lambda function`:

```
df['short_string'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['string'][x['position_1']:x['position_2']], axis=1)
```

Or use list comprehension with `zip`:

```
zipped = zip(df['string'], df['position_1'], df['position_2'])
df['short_string'] = [a[b:c] for a,b,c in zipped]
print (df)
  string  position_1  position_2 short_string
0   aabb           0           3          aab
1   ddcc           1           4          dcc
```

Comment: Ah yes, the lambda function - my nemesis, if I knew you better, I would have slept better :)